# Keep retrying Celery task and only move on if task succeeds or max retries reached

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a Celery task that retries on failure with exponential backoff. This task POSTs messages received by a Django application (call it "transport") to a second Django application (call it "base") for processing. These messages have to be processed in order, and so the order in which the tasks are queued must be maintained. However, when a task fails (because transport cannot connect to base for whatever reason), it is relegated to the back of the queue, which is obviously an issue.

Is it possible to "block" a Celery queue, ie. to keep retrying the same task until it either succeeds or reaches the max retries threshold, and only then move to the next task in the queue? In my case I need the task at the head of the queue to keep trying that POST until it can't anymore, and under no circumstances should the order of tasks in the queue be changed, though I'm not sure if this can be done with Celery (and if so, how).

I've come across [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29967849/how-to-ensure-task-execution-order-per-user-using-celery-rabbitmq-and-django) which seems to describe a very similar problem, but it's not fully relevant to my use case.

Answer (score 0):

If your tasks are chained together, celery won't process subsequent tasks until the first one finishes. So you could do:

```
@task(bind=True, acks_late=True)
def retry_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # do stuff
    except PossibleExceptions:
        self.retry()

def next_task(*args, **kwargs):
    # foo

task_signature = retry_task.si() | next_task.si()
task_signature.apply_async()
```

Please read the documentation on [retrying](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-retry-for-known-exceptions). It has a lot of new features since I've last looked at it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @shillingt, however I'm not sure this is directly applicable. In my case, I have only the one task, which is called every time the transport receives a message. I need these instances of the _same_ task to run in order (and for failure and retry to not break said order). Is it possible to somehow retrieve the task at the tail of the queue, so that I can chain new incoming tasks to that task specifically - thereby maintaining queue order?

Comment: It might be, but in my experience, that doesn't sound like a great idea. If I were you, I'd revisit how things are structured to see if I can accomplish the end results in a different manner that's compatible with the more typical Celery features.